# MS Office is not showing in the uninstall or change a program list but works properly. How to fully uninstall it?

Tags: windows-10

I was trying to do an online repair of MS Office 16 when the internet connection was severed.

After that the MS Office disappeared from the list of programs in the programs and features of the control panel. But I can still open the MS Office.

Is there a way to uninstall it now?

Comment: Repair it again and then uninstall?